# Why does default-initialization of reference type member result in compiler warning?

Tags: c++, reference, constants, compiler-warnings

I have the following code:

```
class A {
 public:
  A() { }
};

class B {
 private:
  const A &a;

 public:
  B() : a() { }
  B(const A &ina) : a(ina) { }
};
```

Compiling results in the following:

> ab.cpp: In constructor 'B::B()':
>
> ab.cpp:11: warning: default-initialization of 'const A& B::a', which has reference type

Why does this result in a warning and how do I fix it?

Comment: References always need to refer to something. Your default constructor would leave the reference dangling.

Comment: Default initializing a reference doesn't really make much sense. What is it referencing? Hint: nothing

Comment: References must be initialized to *something* (ie. an existing object). Actually I'm quite surprised you only get a warning and not an error.

Comment: Oh, dear. What I *actually* wanted was to call the default constructor... :/

Comment: @NikolaNovak In that case, why not hold the `A` by value, rather than by reference?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what compiler (and version) are you using?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young good question, I think it's because of the second constructor - I didn't want to pass by value, or copy object A. On the other hand, looking at the code which prompted this post, I probably should have a superclass for B and then have another class which inherits from it, which has a parameterless constructor and doesn't contain A by reference, because it doesn't need A at all in that case.

Comment: @NikolaNovak Yeah, that's probably a more sensible approach.

Comment: @syam the system I'm working on has 'gcc version 4.1.1 20070105 (Red Hat 4.1.1-52)'. I would also like to know why, but the admin prefers to laugh at me when I ask such silly questions, rather than give me a straight answer.

Comment: @NikolaNovak This is a very old version (2007-01, ie. 6.5 years old! Remember that C++11 was released in... 2011). No wonder you're getting this kind of weird diagnostics. ;) As to why your admins won't upgrade such an old system, well, that's beyond me. Even Debian oldstable (squeeze) is not as outdated as that (which is saying a lot...).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

References in C++ language can be thought of as "alternative names" for other objects. A name always refers to an object, it cannot exist without that object, i.e. a reference cannot "refer to nothing". This means that a reference has to be bound to the target object immediately, at the moment of reference creation, and stay bound to that object as long as that reference exists. The language is specifically designed to enforce that rule as much as possible. In case of reference members inside a non-aggregate class type, such members have to be explicitly initialized in constructor initializer list.

Strictly speaking a program that calls for default initialization of a reference is ill-formed. In everyday nomenclature, it is supposed to be an "error", not a "warning". So, the real "why" here is why your compiler issued a mere warning (albeit formally any diagnostic message is sufficient to report ill-formed code).

Comment: The language definition requires **a diagnostic**. There is only one case in which it requires that a compiler refuse to compile code, and that's when it encounters a `#error` directive. Other than that, what constitutes a diagnostic is implementation-defined, and having issued a diagnostic, the compiler is free to continue to compile the code. That's the hook for implementation-specific extensions. So "in everyday nomenclature" a warning (mere or otherwise) is all that's required.

Answer (score 5):

From the standard :

> **8.5.3 References [dcl.init.ref]**
>
> 1. A variable declared to be a T& or T&&, that is, “reference to type T” (8.3.2), shall be initialized by an object, or function, of type T or by an object that can be converted into a T.
> 2. [...]
> 3. The initializer can be omitted for a reference only in a parameter declaration (8.3.5), in the declaration of a function return type, in the declaration of a class member within its class definition (9.2), and where the extern specifier is explicitly used.

The constructor of `B` is wrong because internally it calls the default constructor of a reference, this is not possible.

A reference member has to be initialize int the *member-initialization-list* of the constructors. That's why your default constructor is ill-formed.

Answer (score 2):

It is UB. References have to always be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

A reference should always refer to a variable. Therefore default initialization in the 1st constructor for B does not make sense. In effect having a reference that was default-initialized is the same as having a pointer that was not initialized at all: both refer to (or point to) a random place in memory. Thus the warning.